# android okhttp post get "length required"message with 411 return code

Tags: android, okhttp

I'm trying to use okhttp lib on my android app post PNG file to server.The server return 411 code ,the response message is "Length required".
My code :

```
RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
                .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
                .addPart(
                        Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"sendto\""),
                        RequestBody.create(null, sendtoJsonStr))
                .addPart(
                        Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"picture\""),
                        RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, new File(filePath)))
                .build();
    long l = requestBody.contentLength();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(requestBody)
            .addHeader("Authorization","Token "+ UserLogin.getInstance().getLoginToken())

            .build();

    Response response = mClient.newCall(request).execute();
```

I have tried to use okhttp lib RequestBody class  contentLength() function, but does't work.

Anyone can help me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is fixed in [this issue](https://github.com/square/okhttp/pull/969) and already merged into master. You can either wait for the 2.1 release of OkHttp or clone the repo and build the 2.1-SNAPSHOT JAR yourself.

**EDIT**: [OkHttp 2.1 is out.](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-210)